# Cálculo de média móvel no MATLAB

Tags: matemática, matlab

Como calcular a média de 12 meses de uma série temporal no MATLAB, de forma que, fixando jan a dez o ano que se quer a média, o mês de jan do ano x é a média de jan a dez do ano x-1, o mês de fev do ano x é a média de fev do ano x-1 a jan do ano x e o mês mar do ano x será a media de mar do ano x-1 a fev do ano x?

Answer (score 1):

Infelizmente não sabemos de qual maneira seus dados estão estruturados, então para te ajudar vamos supor que sua série temporal seja algo do tipo:

```
Ano = 2014:
Janeiro = [1 2 7 8 9];
Fevereiro = [3 4 5];
Março = [5 2 5 0]
.
.
.
etc
```

O mesmo principio seria para o ano de 2013, etc, etc!

A primeira recomendação é colocar seus valores em `Structs`, isso vai facilitar a manipulação dos dados, estamos falando em colocar seus dados desta maneira:

```
A2014 = struct('1', [1 2 7 8 9], '2',[3 4 5],  '3',[5 2 5 0], '4',[9 2 0 0], '5',[33 1 5 90 200], '6',[82 4], '7',[5 2 5 0], '8',[31 6], '9',[9 0 3 4 5], '10',[2 0], '11',[7], '12',[2 9 0 3]);

A2013 = struct('1', [4 7 5], '2',[2 3 6 6],  '3',[22 3 4 5], '4',[1 3 3 5], '5',[9 6 5 5 20], '6',[1 3 5 4], '7',[4 0], '8',[1 5 6 6], '9',[3 5 5], '10',[1 4 4], '11',[2 7 5], '12',[5 5 5 1]);
```

Eu gerei valores randômicos e de tamanhos diferentes, mas isso não importa, é só para te mostrar o conceito, repare que eu atribui cada mês com o seu número correspondente, cada ano recebe uma `struct` com a série temporal de cada mês.

A lógica pode ser feita de diferentes maneiras, imagine a seguinte entrada:

```
anodesejado = XXXX
mesdesejado = X
```

A equação para caminhar entre os Meses/Ano seria `(12 - (13-mesdesejado))`, se esse cálculo for igual a `zero(0)` caminhe do `mesdesejado` até o mês `12` do `anodesejado-1`, se o cálculo for diferente de `zero(0)` caminhe do `mesdesejado` até o mês `12` do `anodesejado-1` e de `1` até `(12 - (13-mesdesejado))`  do `anodesejado`.

Claro não esqueça de somar seus valores dentro de cada loop e no final dividir por `12`, assim terá sua média!

Segue a lógica descrita acima em código Matlab:

```
%Entre com os valores desejados
anodesejado = 2014
mesdesejado = 1


A2014 = struct('1', [1 2 7 8 9], '2',[3 4 5],  '3',[5 2 5 0], '4',[9 2 0 0], '5',[33 1 5 90 200], '6',[82 4], '7',[5 2 5 0], '8',[31 6], '9',[9 0 3 4 5], '10',[2 0], '11',[7], '12',[2 9 0 3]);
A2013 = struct('1', [4 7 5], '2',[2 3 6 6],  '3',[22 3 4 5], '4',[1 3 3 5], '5',[9 6 5 5 20], '6',[1 3 5 4], '7',[4 0], '8',[1 5 6 6], '9',[3 5 5], '10',[1 4 4], '11',[2 7 5], '12',[5 5 5 1]);


soma=0;

if (12 - (13-mesdesejado)) == 0

  for M=mesdesejado:12

    soma = soma + sum(eval(["A" num2str(anodesejado-1)]).(num2str(M)));
  end
else
    for M=mesdesejado:12

    soma = soma + sum(eval(["A" num2str(anodesejado-1)]).(num2str(M)));
    end 
    for M=1:(12 - (13-mesdesejado))

    soma = soma + sum(eval(["A" num2str(anodesejado)]).(num2str(M)));
    end 



end

media = soma/12
```

Comment: Ederwander, obrigado pela resposta, vou tentar implementá-la.